# Bedeutung von "Das Hü und Hott"

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet der Ausdruck "das Hü und Hott" im folgenden Satz:

> **Das Hü und Hott** bei Marvels Gambit-Film nimmt einfach kein Ende.

Comment: Wo hast du diesen Satz her? Ohne etwas mehr Kontext ist das nicht ganz eindeutig.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Hü* und *Hott* sind alte Pferdekutschkommandos, wobei *Hü Laufen* bedeuten kann und *Links*, *Hott* aber nur *Rechts* während *Stehen* mit *Brr* bedeutet wird.

Der übertragene Sinn sollte klar sein: Die Führung weiß nicht was sie will, die Anweisungen sind widersprüchlich, es gibt keine stringente Marschdevise, mal geht es hier lang, mal dort.

Mehr Details in der [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuhrkommando#H.C3.BCst_und_Hott).

Comment: Das klingt richtig, aber mit etwas Kontext könnten wir es genauer sagen, wie @idmean festgestellt hat.

Comment: Ich bin über das "alte" im ersten Satz deiner Antwort gestolpert. Ich wunder mich darüber das es dort steht, da ich bei dir immer das Gefühl einer präzisen nutzung von Worten habe. Du hast weder veraltet noch veraltend verwendet was mich zu dem Gedanken brachte das es vielleicht neue Kommandos gibt die sich *noch* nicht vollständig durchgesetzt haben. Natürlich könnte es sein das du nur darauf hinweisen wolltest, dass diese Kommandos schon lange in Verwendung sind allerdings sehe ich dafür hier keinen guten Grund. Ich konnte nichts entsprechendes im Internet finden. Eine Aufklärung wäre nett.

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda: Ich habe im Alltag nichts mit Pferden zu tun. Ich weiß nicht, ob die Kommandos noch in Gebrauch sind oder nicht. Aus den Medien weiß ich, dass sie es früher waren. Wenn 1980 Forscher herausgefunden hätten, dass andere Kommandos besser geeignet sind und sich das seither durchgesetzt hätte, wüsste ich davon wahrscheinlich nichts.

Comment: Als Kommando zum Stoppen eines Pferdes kenne ich nur Brrr. Somit ist Hott nicht das Gegenteil von Hü. Es soll aber wohl mit dem Ausdruck "Hü und Hott" der Anschein erweckt werden, dass etwas nicht in eine Richtung läuft. Siehe auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuhrkommando

Comment: @Harper: Danke, habe es korrigiert.